# Clear explanation of acceleration of the earth

Tags: acceleration, vectors, velocity, earth, rotation

The Earth rotates with an angular velocity of $\omega$.

My questions:

1. Is the angular acceleration of the Earth equal to $0$ because angular velocity is stable?
2. What is the difference between angular acceleration and the acceleration of the Earth's gravity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes there is no angular acceleration.(except a very little by the tides)
2. The attraction between masses which causes the gravitation, has nothing to do with the rotation, The exact force on a mass on earth ist a little diminished by centrifugal force